# How can I disable a RigidBody?

Tags: unity, c#

I have tried to set Rigibody enabled to false with this code but I get multiple errors. What is the correct version of this code?

```
GetComponent<RigidBody>().Enabled = false;
```

Comment: It would help a lot when you would tell us what these "multiple errors" are.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, it helps if you actually post the errors you're getting.

In this case, however, the problem seems straightforward: [RigidBody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) does not have a member named `Enabled`.

It sounds like you want to set both [`isKinematic`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) and [`detectCollisions`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-detectCollisions.html) to `false`.

Comment: As for why `RigidBody` does not have a member named `enabled`: `enabled` is a member of `Behaviour` and not `Component`. `Rigidbody` derives from `Component` directly.

Comment: isKinematic works the other way round, see @HappyGoLucky comment.

Answer (score 2):

@user1430's answer is good, but you actually set `isKinematic` to `true` to disable the rigidbody, per [isKinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) docs.

```
// Let animation control the rigidbody and ignore collisions.
void DisableRagdoll()
{
    rb.isKinematic = true;
    rb.detectCollisions = false;
}
```

I would have added this as a comment to @user1430's answer but don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score -2):

In Unity 4.0+ rigidbody.active is deprecated and may no longer be available but you can do this:

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = false;
```

Comment: This seems to be a subset of the advice already present in Josh's answer from four years ago. Do you have any new recommendations to add?